# module: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, magento, logging, error-handling

I've ensured the file is there. Permissions are set correct as well.

```
 Warning: include(Mage/olc/Search/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/te/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

This is so confusing, can anybody clue me in on what do look for to fix this.

```
#0 /home/te/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Vo...', '/home/te...', 93, Array)
#1 /home/te/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_olc_Sea...')
#3 /home/te/public_html/app/Mage.php(547): spl_autoload_call('Mage_olc_Sea...')
#4 /home/te/public_html/app/design/frontend/enterprise/olc/template/page/html/head.phtml(34): Mage::helper('olc_search')
#5 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/te...')
#6 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#7 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /home/te/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /home/te/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /home/te/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#11 /home/te/public_html/app/design/frontend/enterprise/olc/template/page/1column.phtml(35): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#12 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/te...')
#13 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#14 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /home/te/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#18 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#19 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#20 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#21 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#22 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#23 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /home/te/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 /home/te/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 /home/te/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where the helper is being used?

Comment: @MladenIlić, posted the rest of the stack above.

Comment: The thing that seems weird here is Magento autoloader evaluated class path with lowercase module namespace (I'm talking about `.../olc/...` part of the `include` statement).

My bet is that helpers are not properly configured in *config.xml*. If you need any extra help, don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing my xml file located inside of: /app/etc/modules